# How to use Certificate Authentication with the REST connector in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'd like to use some of the more advanced features of the REST Dataset in Azure Data Factory (mainly pagination), but I can't see where to use Certificate Authentication.  I have an HTTP Dataset working well with Certificate Authentication, but the only options seem to be:

- Anonymous
- Basic
- AAD Service Principal
- Managed Identity

Is there some way to use the AAD Service Principal or Managed Identity with a certificate?  Maybe I can do this using the Advanced settings?

The docs say that the HTTP connector is "less functional comparing to REST connector" but this seems to be a pretty big omission from the REST version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to use the AAD Service Principal or Managed Identity
>   with a certificate? Maybe I can do this using the Advanced settings?

SP and MI can't be applied for the certificate authentication, for AAD instead. please refer to this simple [blog](https://thecloudhub.com/2019/03/whats-an-azure-service-principal-and-managed-identity/).

Based on the [REST Connector document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest),it only supports above 4 types of authenticate options. If you want to carry certificate with request,please use [HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http) connector.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit an enhancement via gtihub.